# How to identify which xterm a shell or process is running in?

Tags: window-manager, xterm

I usually use long running X sessions with several virtual desktops and many many xterms.

I also use job control in the shell (zsh).

Sometimes I wish I could identify an xterm a shell or process is running in (or even suspended in) with a simple command.

For example, you edit a file with vim and vim warns you that it is already opened with another vim instance which is still running. But now you have forgotten in which xterm this vim with process-id XYZ was started and suspended. Killing it does not work, because it is suspended. Resuming it via a signal and then killing could work, but it may screw up an in-foreground running process and perhaps you don't want to kill the vim instance because it has several windows set up ...

Currently I am using awesomewm, but I am also interested in solutions for other wms.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Xterm puts the variable `WINDOWID` in the environment of its subprocess. Its value is the window ID of the xterm window. There is no POSIX way of querying the environment of a process based on its PID; here's a Linux way of querying the environment of process `$pid` and extracting the `WINDOWID` variable:

```
</proc/$pid/environ gawk -v 'RS=\0' -F = '$1=="WINDOWID" {print $2}'
```

You can then find or act on the window with `wmctrl` or through your window manager's interface.

If you use screen, first try the `STY` variable, which is set to the name of the screen session. You can connect to that session with `screen -rd -S "$sessionname"`.

Comment: That will only work with gawk. mawk (the default on Debian and possibly Ubuntu) does not handle a NUL record separator. Another way to extract the environment of a process is `xargs -n 1 -0 < /proc/$PID/environ`

Comment: @camh: Thanks. (More precisely, `/usr/bin/awk` is gawk by default on Debian and Ubuntu but only if you've installed gawk or one of its few dependencies.) Another way of parsing `/proc/$PID/environ` is to `tr '\n\0' '\n\0' | sed -ne 's/^WINDOWID=//p'` (it's even POSIX, but that's moot since the input file isn't).

Answer (score 6):

You can use `ps -o ppid= PID` to get the parent ID of process PID, which will probably be the shell that launched it. The parent ID of that shell will be the terminal containing it.

---

To test, I spawned a process that would stay around for a while:

```
$ sleep 5m &
[1] 31177
```

Then I looked up the parent of process 31177, and what command it is:

```
$ ps -o ppid= 31177
31107
$ ps -o cmd= 31107
zsh
```

31107 is the zsh process I ran the `sleep 5m` in. I repeated that on the `zsh` process

```
$ ps -o ppid= 31107
31097
$ ps -o cmd= 31097
xterm
```

31097 is the `xterm` that my `zsh` shell was running in

---

If you're not sure how far up the parent you want is, you can use this to search for a parent with the given command name:

```
pid="$1"
cmd="$2"

seek=""
while [ "$seek" != "$cmd" ]; do
    # ps -o ppid= $pid
    pid=`ps -o ppid= $pid`
    seek=`ps -o cmd= $pid`

    if [ ${pid/ /} = 1 ]; then
        echo Reached the top of the tree
        exit 1
    fi
done

echo $pid
```

Test:

```
$ /tmp/find-parent 31177 xterm
31097
```

Comment: Rather than stop on a command name, stop when you reach a process with a different controlling terminal (`tty` column in `ps`). That process is the terminal emulator.

Comment: nice command line screencast - that gives me the right xterm PID, to actually find it on your screen a second step is needed, like Gilles pointed out